# UILabel extension, User defined runtime attributes

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, runtime, extension-methods

I would like to know more details how to implement text styles to UILabel.
I want to type String in IBInspectable field in Storyboard, get this value and look for this it in style file (switch case).

I've tried to do this this way:

1. Set "User defined runtime attributes".

   Key Path as style,

   Type as

   String,

   value as "hello"

   I' ve read that I should declare also this property in UILabel class so:

   ```
    extension UILabel{
      var style: String? {
          get(){
             return self.style // it always fails
          }
          set(newValue){
             objc_setAssociatedObject(self, "styleNew", newValue,
             objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN) 
             //instead of self.style = newValue 
          }
      }
   ```

   }

I'm calling it in viewDidAppear method as an Outlet property:

```
 `print("Style", self.infoLabel.valueForKey("styleNew"))`
```

and also

```
 `print("Style", self.infoLabel.styleNew)`
```

When I try to get value it fails. I'm getting "bad_exc_access" error, I've tried to repair it but I don't understand this behavior and on apple.developer is nothing clear. I found only tutorials, issues with cornerRadius, borderColor and staff like that.
I've tried to replace return `return self.styleNew` with `objc_getAssociatedObject(self, "styleNew")`, but it doesn't help too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a computed property and you cannot return itself in the getter.

If you are trying to style the label by setting the style string, I suggest you keep a registry of styles and when the style attribute gets set, just apply the style to the UILabel. I tried to implement something similar with success so you can take a look [here](https://github.com/pgorzelany/Stylish/blob/Style-As-Structs/Stylish/Stylish.swift).

Comment: Your code was very helpful for me, everything works for me fine, but what about get{return "something"} so how can I get properly value without returning itself there? Is it possible? What about setting this value? Actually what do you do there is just call another method witch choose the style. It's strange behavior for me that I can't set getter & setter to itself.